# EF Core - unincluding binrary fields

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I have an EF Core model that has a binary field

```
class SomeModel {
    string Id;
    string otherProperty;
    byte[] blob;
};
```

Usually, when I query the DB, I want to return a list of this Model - and then, on subsequent calls, query just a single entity, but return the blob.

I can't see a way in either data or code first to prevent EF Core paying the cost of retrieving the blob field always.

I really want to be able to say something like:

```
var list = await Context.SomeModels.ToListAsync();

// later
var item = await Context.SomeModels
  .Where(m=>m.Id==someId)
  .Include(m=>m.blob)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I think I might have to put the blobs into a 2nd table so I can force a optional join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could get a separate loading is to move the data to a separate entity with one-to-one relationship.

It doesn't need to be a separate table though. Although the most natural choice looks to be [owned entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities), since owned entities are always loaded with the owners, it has to be a regular entity, but configured with [table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#table-splitting) - in simple words, share the same table with the principal entity.

Applying it to your sample:

*Model:*

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public SomeModelBlob Blob { get; set; }
};

public class SomeModelBlob
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModelBlob>(builder =>
{
    builder.HasOne<SomeModel>().WithOne(e => e.Blob)
        .HasForeignKey<SomeModelBlob>(e => e.Id);
    builder.Property(e => e.Data).HasColumnName("Blob");
    builder.ToTable(modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel>().Metadata.Relational().TableName);
});
```

*Usage:*

Code:

```
var test = context.Set<SomeModel>().ToList();
```

SQL:

```sql
  SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[OtherProperty]
  FROM [SomeModel] AS [s]
```

Code:

```
var test = context.Set<SomeModel>().Include(e => e.Blob).ToList();
```

SQL:

```sql
  SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[OtherProperty], [e].[Id], [e].[Blob]
  FROM [SomeModel] AS [e]
```

(the second `e.Id` in the `select` looks strange, but I guess we can live with that)

Comment: It's nice to see that I can set this up via CodeFirst. But our development process is mostly DB First so I don't see that I can get EF Core scaffold to infer this table split. Is there a document that describes the conventions EF Core scaffold uses to produce its tables as I've been lucky so far in that it builds what appear to be the relationships I have wanted - but it does worryingly generate different fluent code to that which I would have generated manually.

Comment: I don't think the standard EF Core scaffolder allows customization. You may try [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering) or [Entity Framework Core Scaffolding with Handlebars](https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars)